# Що означає слово "козачити"?

Tags: значення-слів

Не раз чув від старших людей такий вислів: "Ну як воно, хлопці, козачете трохи?" Та ніколи не надавав цьому особливого значення, однак нещодавно вирішив перевірити, що воно таки означає і дуже здивувася, коли не зміг знайти цього слова ні в СУМі, ні в Інтернеті взагалі (окрім одного [формуму](http://forum.meta.ua/topic/p/5809727.html) та цієї цитати: " ***Але за багатолюдністю цього містечка наші предки дехто на куплених, а інші на зайнятих по стародавнім вольностям козачити…*** " з [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%96), однак  я не зміг зрозуміти, що ж означає це слово).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ЕСУМ каже, що козакувати або козачити означає "бути козаком, парубком". Також у російській "козачить" або "казачить" означає "працювати, батрачити".

[image: козакувати]

---

Також цікаво, що відоме значення слова "убивати" в олонецькому діалекті (на території колишньої Олонецької губернії на кордоні з Фінляндією) як вияв ксенофобії до козаків: ["Словарь областного олонецкого наречия в его бытовом и этнографическом применении"](http://136.243.13.116:88/Viewer.html?file=/Book/pdf/101018.pdf) (с. 38 у словнику і с. 47 у PDF)